# Smoothly move Image with accelerometer in android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am building an android application similar to x-ray scanner ([Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kreci.xray&hl=en)), which moves images smoothly on screen by moving the device left,right top and bottom.

I am using accelerometer for this, but problem is that image is not moving smoothly.
My code is below

```
int x1 = (int) sensorEvent.values[0]*(screenW/10);
int y1 = (int) sensorEvent.values[1]*(screenH/14);
```

and then in on Draw
`canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, mPaint);`

Comment: Sensors can add quite a bit of jitter.  In order to get smooth movements, you typically need to do some sort of Fourier Transform over multiple sensor values to smoothen the output. Occassionally the effect is done by combining a gyro with the accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you use them. You should take current value and ADD to current position instead of setting position from value directly. The more you tilt - the bigger values you will get and hence the faster the image will appear to move. 
You can then also apply some linear interpolation to the movement so that it appears smoother.

Here is a link to learn more about lerp (linear interpolation) in code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Programming_language_support